# Basic Geometry Problem : FInd $AC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quartics

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle where $\angle B$ is a right angle. Extend $AC$ up to point $D$ such that $\angle CBD=30^\circ$. If $AB=CD=1$, find $AC$.

My approach to this problem is first to try to find some similarity among the triangle, but did not succeed to find any similar triangle. I then try to use some trigonometry to solve the problem, such as the law of sine, but again, did not succeed.

Any hint of solution to this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Set $AC=x$ and use $\cos(\angle BAC)=1/x$, $\sin(\angle BAC)=\sqrt{x^2-1}/x$, $\angle BDA=60°-\angle BAC$.

Comment: Do i use law of sine in the triangle ABD after that ? Now I have an equation of $x$ but some are in the square root. What should I do with it ? @Aretino

Comment: Get rid of the square root with the usual manipulations (isolate the square root on one side and then square both sides). You'll end with a quartic equation for $x$, which can be factored as $(x+2)(x^3-2)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AC=x$. Notice $\angle ACB=\sin^{-1} \frac 1x$ and so $\angle BCD=\pi -\sin^{-1} \frac 1x$. Using the Law of Sines, $$\frac{\sin 30^\circ}{1}=\frac{\sin\left(\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac 1x\right)}{BD} \implies BD=\frac 2x$$ Now use the Law of Cosines on $\triangle BCD$:

$$\cos 30^\circ = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}=\frac{(\sqrt{x^2-1})^2 + \frac{4}{x^2} -1}{2\sqrt{x^2-1}\cdot \frac{2}{x}} \\ \implies t^4-4t^3-4t+16=0 \\ \implies t=4, 2^{\frac 23}$$ where $t=x^2$ and hence $x=2,2^{\frac 13}$.

Comment: The solution $x=2$ is spurious.

Comment: @Aretino I pondered over this for quite a while. Can you justify why it is so?

Comment: Because the "right" solution would be $x=-2$, see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AC=x$ and $DE$ be an altitude of $\Delta BCD$.

Thus, $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta DEC,$ which gives $$\frac{DE}{1}=\frac{1}{x}$$ or $$DE=\frac{1}{x}$$ and since $\measuredangle DBC=30^{\circ},$ we obtain $$BD=\frac{2}{x}$$ and by the Pythagoras's theorem $$BF=\frac{\sqrt3}{x}.$$

In another hand, by Pythagoras again we obtain:
$$BE=BC+CE=\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}},$$ which gives
$$\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt3}{x}$$ or $$(1+x)\sqrt{x^2-1}=\sqrt3$$ or
$$x^4+2x^3-2x-4=0$$ or
$$(x+2)(x^3-2)=0,$$ which gives $$x=\sqrt[3]2.$$